# chartjs not loading data from same page, picking data from unknow soruce

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

i am working with chartjs, my javascript data is on the same page with div id, but its picking the chart from another source. However, i want the data to be picked from my same page

below is my javascript

```
<script>
    if($("#line-chartjsid2").length){

        var lineChartData = {
            labels:  ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul" , "Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Income",
                fillColor: "rgba(63,81,181,0.5)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(63,81,181,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(63,81,181,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(63,81,181,1)",
                data: [<?php echo $jantotinc; ?>,<?php echo $febtotinc ?>,<?php echo $martotinc ?>,<?php echo $aprtotinc ?>,<?php echo $maytotinc ?>,<?php echo $juntotinc ?>,<?php echo $jultotinc ?>,<?php echo $augtotinc ?>,<?php echo $septotinc ?>,<?php echo $octtotinc ?>,<?php echo $novtotinc ?>,<?php echo $dectotinc ?>]
            }, {
                label: "Expense",
                fillColor: "rgba(255,58,183,0.5)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(255,58,183,1.0)",
                pointColor: "rgba(255,58,183,1.0)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(255,58,183,1.0)",
                data: [<?php echo $jantotbill; ?>,<?php echo $febtotbill; ?>,<?php echo $martotbill; ?>,<?php echo $aprtotbill; ?>,<?php echo $maytotbill; ?>,<?php echo $juntotbill; ?>,<?php echo $jultotbill; ?>,<?php echo $augtotbill; ?>,<?php echo $septotbill; ?>,<?php echo $octtotbill; ?>,<?php echo $novtotbill; ?>,<?php echo $dectotbill; ?>]
            }]

        }

        var ctx = document.getElementById("line-chartjsid2").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
            responsive: true
        });

}
</script>
```

and this is my code

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <section class="box ">
            <header class="panel_header">
                <h2 class="title pull-left">Expenses</h2>
                <div class="actions panel_actions pull-right">
                    <a class="box_toggle fa fa-chevron-down"></a>
                    <!--<a class="box_setting fa fa-cog" data-toggle="modal" href="#section-settings"></a>
                    <a class="box_close fa fa-times"></a> -->
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="content-body">    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="chart-container">
                     <!-- <div class="" style="height:200px" id="platform_type_dates"></div>-->
                       <canvas id="line-chartjsid2" style="height: 200px; width: 100%;"></canvas>
                  </div>
        </div>      
    </div> <!-- End .row -->
    </div>
        </section></div>
```

Please i want to pick this same data from my page

Comment: Have you tried to remove the echo in php data parts?

Comment: yes i even replaced it with raw numbers